# Should a client handle an url ending with "?" but no parameters?

Tags: parsing, url, client-server

A `url` without parameters but with a question mark appended at the end is passed to the client to be parsed and used.

I've been told the client should be robust enough to handle such url and proceed. But shouldn't this be fixed server-side?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

An empty query part is not an error, so it definitely needs to be accepted by the client. (Reference: [RFC 3986 section 3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) which shows the syntax of the query as 0 or more allowable characters.)

An empty query is different from an undefined query (i.e., the URI does not contain a `?`). If the base URI contains a query component, merging a relative URI with an empty query will override the base URI's query, whereas merging a relative URI without a query will copy the base URI's query into the merged result.